# How to pass data from html form elements to the angular class

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-forms

I'm using `angular 9` and I need to bind HTML forms data to the angular class.
I have the following angular class:

```
export interface MyData {
    field1: string,
    textArea1: string,
    textArea2: string
}
```

and I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <label>Field1</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Process id"/>
        <label>TextArea1</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea"></textarea>
        <label>TextArea2</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea"></textarea>
      </div>
```

How can I bind data from the HTML form to the `MyData` angular class?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: @MikeS. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use Angular Form for that ?

In your component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-your-component-selector',
 templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent {
 /** new form group instance */
 form: FormGroup;

 constructor() {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
     this.initForm();
 }

 initForm(): void {
    /** field1, textArea1, textArea2 are form control instances */
    this.form = new FormGroup({
        field1: new FormControl(''),
        textArea1: new FormControl(''),
        textArea2: new FormControl(''),
    });
 }

 onSubmit(): void {
   // code here after submit
   console.info(this.form.value);
 }
}
```

A form group tracks the status and changes for each of its controls, so if one of the controls changes, the parent control also emits a new status or value change.

In your template:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <label>Field1</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="field1" aria-label="Process id"/>

    <label>TextArea1</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" formControlName="textArea1" aria-label="With textarea"></textarea>

    <label>TextArea2</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" formControlName="textArea2" aria-label="With textarea"></textarea>
  </form>
</div>
```

More information [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)